# MySQL crashes and currently the error.log file is huge

Tags: mysql, innodb, optimization

I've created a droplet on DigitalOcean created using Laravel Forge 6 months ago. Two weeks ago, we decided it was time to upgrade the droplet and we moved from a 4GB RAM/2CPUs to a 16GB RAM/6CPUs droplet and since a few days ago the MySQL server just crashes and the only way to make it work again is by rebooting the server (MySQL makes the server unresponsive).

When I type htop to see the list of processes is showing a few of `/usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysql.pid` (currently is showing more than 30 entries like that).

The error log is bigger than 1GB (yes, I know!) and shows this message hundreds of times:

`[Warning] InnoDB: Difficult to find free blocks in the buffer pool (21 search iterations)! 21 failed attempts to flush a page! Consider increasing the buffer pool size. It is also possible that in your Unix version fsync is very slow, or completely frozen inside the OS kernel. Then upgrading to a newer version of your operating system may help. Look at the number of fsyncs in diagnostic info below. Pending flushes (fsync) log: 0; buffer pool: 0. 167678974 OS file reads, 2271392 OS file writes, 758043 OS fsyncs. Starting InnoDB Monitor to print further diagnostics to the standard output.`

The only thing that changed recently is now we send weekly notifications to customers (only the ones that subscribed to it) to let them know about certain events happening in the current week. This is kind of a intensive process, because we have a few thousands of customers, but we take advantage of Laravel Queues in order to process everything.

I've tried to change `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from the default value to 80% of available RAM (~13GB) and instead of the previous message, now it's showing:

`"InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took 4228ms. The settings might not be optimal."`.

And this change made the database run slower. For example, to process 30k records (the notifications thing that I mentioned) it took 6 hours but before the change it was taking around 3 (when it didn't crashed).

Is this a MySQL-settings related issue?

EDIT: Global Status and Variables after innodb_* suggested changes

[Show Variables](https://pastebin.com/kRXz87dZ) and [Show Global Status](https://pastebin.com/HDyw1mpK)

Comment: What version of MySQL?  What queries are running when it happens?  Do you have long-running transactions?  Please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'm using mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.24, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper. I've edited the question to include screenshots with innodb variables. Regarding the queries, honestly it's very random. I couldn't identify a pattern. It just happened again and the query.log file this time is 8GB. Do you have any idea what it could be the reason? Thanks

Comment: Hi @RickJames! I've found a nice article written by you (http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/memory) and I've changed the values of innodb_buffer_pool_size to 12G and key_buffer_size to 10MB. I've just checked the error.log and I've noticed the following error “Got an error reading communication packets”, without doing anything "intensive". I tried to truncate a table with 30K records and insert all of them again and I got “InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took XXX ms. The settings might not be optimal"

Comment: I'm still trying to get a handle on "page_cleaners".  Was the `TRUNCATE` against a MyISAM table or an InnoDB table?  How did you do the reinsert?  `LOAD DATA`?  `INSERT one row at a time?  Batch insert?

Comment: Actually it was a ```delete from where condition```. It was made against a InnoDB table. The reinsert was a script that loads information from an external system (in JSON format), parses the information and inserts the records one row at a time. Thanks!

Comment: `DELETE .. WHERE ..` -- This might work efficiently; it might work terribly.  If it delete removes several thousand rows, it _may_ have precipitated the page_cleaner problem.  See [_this_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig) for several safer ways to delete lots of rows.

Answer (score 1):

For the 4GB droplet, change the config: `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 1500M and restart.

For the 16GB droplet, change the config:

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
innodb_page_cleaners = 12
```

**Revised Analysis**  (After running more than a day)

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 1d 02:59:16
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

A lot of table scans and many are big.  This *may* be interfering with other InnoDB operations, hence *indirectly* stalling the page_cleaners.

Change to `innodb_lru_scan_depth = 256` as a possible solution to the page_cleaner problem.

**Details and other observations:**

`( innodb_lru_scan_depth ) = 1,024`
-- "InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took ..." may be fixed by lowering lru_scan_depth

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 511,813 / 786384 = 65.1%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size is bigger than necessary?

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_bytes_data / innodb_buffer_pool_size ) = 4,456,398,848 / 12288M = 34.6%` -- Percent of buffer pool taken up by data
-- A small percent *may* indicate that the buffer_pool is unnecessarily big.

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( join_buffer_size / _ram ) = 262,144 / 16384M = 0.00%` -- 0-N per thread. May speed up JOINs (better to fix queries/indexes) (all engines) Used for index scan, range index scan, full table scan, each full JOIN, etc.
-- If large, decrease join_buffer_size to avoid memory pressure. Suggest less than 1% of RAM. If small, increase to 0.01% of RAM to improve some queries.

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( Handler_read_rnd_next / Com_select ) = 10,900,684,560 / 1418310 = 7,685` -- Avg rows scanned per SELECT. (approx)
-- Consider raising read_buffer_size (128K now; unclear whether raising it will help)

`( Select_scan ) = 233,714 / 97156 = 2.4 /sec` -- full table scans
-- Add indexes / optimize queries (unless they are tiny tables)

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 233,714 / 1418310 = 16.5%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( Connections ) = 131,201 / 97156 = 1.4 /sec` -- Connections
-- Increase wait_timeout; use pooling?

**Abnormally small:**

```
Innodb_dblwr_pages_written / Innodb_dblwr_writes = 2.31
```

**Abnormally large:**

```
Com_show_plugins = 0.26 /HR
Com_show_privileges = 0.037 /HR
Com_stmt_close = 21 /sec
Com_stmt_execute = 21 /sec
Com_stmt_prepare = 21 /sec
Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free = 511,813
Performance_schema_file_instances_lost = 9
innodb_page_cleaners = 12
performance_schema_max_file_classes = 80
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes = 210
```

**Abnormal strings:**

```
innodb_fast_shutdown = 1
innodb_large_prefix = ON
log_slow_admin_statements = ON
```

Comment: Hello @Rick James! Thanks very much for your reply. I will change the config as suggested and test it. I really appreciate your help. Thanks very much!

Comment: Hello @Rick James. Sorry to bother again, but unfortunately I cannot get rid of ```InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took XXXms. The settings might not be optimal.```. The output of [show variables](https://pastebin.com/RJk7aSS9) and  [show global status](https://pastebin.com/hygfKfJK). The strange thing is, this error message is being shown without any intensive operation running (no massive delete/inserts), just a normal/regular day.

Comment: @TJistooshort - I added an analysis.  And, no bother.  "Page_cleaners" has shown up a lot; I would like to find a decent solution.  If you can get a full day's `STATUS`, post them again; 'maybe' there will be a clue.

Comment: Thanks very much. Here are the results of [show variables](https://pastebin.com/e1mb0245) and [show global status](https://pastebin.com/apVBvUG7) after 24 hours. Thanks!

Comment: I reviewed the new output.  See suggestion on `innodb_lru_scan_depth`

Comment: Hello @Rick James!, Thanks very much again. I've changed ```innodb_lru_scan_depth``` as suggested but the message is still there ```InnoDB: page_cleaner: 1000ms intended loop took XXXms. The settings might not be optimal.```. I waited 24 hours with the new setting and updated my question with show variables and show global status. I have one table with 6M records and a few other tables with almost 1M records. Do you think those tables could be the reason of this error? Thanks very much for all your help, I really appreciate that

Comment: A million-row table is only at the 80th percentile.  100M rows gets exciting.  That is, I don't think the new tables are relevant.  Alas, I am running out of ideas on the page_cleaner problem.  (You are not alone in having the problem.)  Let's try to 'fix' the slow queries.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @RickJames. I've been checking the slow query log and, the slowest queries are related to inserts in big tables. I have a few log tables that log different things. The largest one is the 6M records table but the others keep growing as well. I'm not sure how mysql handles millions of records but it seems it's consuming lots of resources (mainly system memory) on busy days. These "log" tables all have one primary key and one FK key.

Comment: @TJistooshort - Hmmm...  How about start a new Question with the specifics of "slow inserts" into "big tables".  Please provide the snippet from the slowlog, `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, the size of the table, a sample 'slow' `INSERT`, RAM size, `innodb_buffer_pool_size` setting, etc.  _Normally_ there is not a lot of difference in performance between inserting into a 1K-row table and into a 1-billion-row table.  So, we are missing something subtle that is causing _your_ inserts to be "slow".

Comment: Hello @Rick James! Thanks for your reply. Initially I thought that the ```INSERT``` wasn't related to this, so I already created another question for that [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/222979/insert-sometimes-takes-more-than-2-seconds-in-table-with-6-million-records). Thanks very much for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Dec 23, 2018  Rate Per Second=RPS  --  Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section, using GLOBAL STATUS and GLOBAL VARIABLES data from your Nov 22, 2O18 to pastebin.com data

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 66,492
innodb_io_capacity=5000  # from 200 to enable higher IOPS on your SSD
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 256 to reduce CPU busy every SECOND
tmp_table_size=32M  # from 16M to expand capacity
max_heap_table_size=32M  # from 16M to reduce created_tmp_disk_tables below 39%
```

Observation, with Linux OS we usually see

```
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT     and you have 0 for the global variable.
```

For additional suggestions, please view my profile, Network profile and get in touch with me.  Happy Holidays.