# Insert sometimes takes more than 2 seconds in table with +6 million records

Tags: mysql, insert

I have a table in my database that acts like a log to record accesses to some selected endpoints of my application.

That table contains:

- id (primary key)
- The http method (GET, POST, PUT, etc)
- The endpoint, some useful data that might be passed
- If the request was made by a logged in user, the user_id. Otherwise user_id is NULL (meaning that the request was made by a guest).

This table is starting to get big (already more than 6 million records) and sometimes the insert statements take more than 2 seconds. We don't perform "intensive" operations in this table: just `INSERT` and `SELECT * FROM table WHERE user_id = xxxx`.

Is it normal that sometimes this insert is done quickly and sometimes it takes more than 2 seconds? What can be done to reduce this time?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

Table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE `user_actions` (
      `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `http_method` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `endpoint` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
      `request_data` text COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `user_id` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
      `user_agent` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
      `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      `updated_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
      KEY `user_actions_user_id_foreign` (`user_id`),
      CONSTRAINT `user_actions_user_id_foreign`
      FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`) REFERENCES `users` (`id`) 
      ON DELETE NO ACTION 
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6312242 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

This is an example of one INSERT statement that took 5.3 seconds:

```
insert into `user_actions` 
   (`http_method`, `route_name`, `query_string`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `request_data`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) 
values 
   ('GET', '19-chars-string', '64-chars-string', '123.123.123.123', '139-chars-string', '[]', 96411, '2018-11-29 18:49:08', '2018-11-29 18:49:08');
```

```
Server RAM = 16GB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 12G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 12
innodb_page_cleaners = 12
```

Comment: Please show us the table definition including any indexes it might have.

Comment: A lot of possible answers...  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Of special relevance:  Engine, number of unique indexes, datatypes, etc.  Also, how many rows are involved in the "slow" query?  How much RAM?  Value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`?

Comment: Hello guys, thanks for your replies. I've edited the question to include the requested details. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you try to remove the FK constrained?

Comment: Hello @eckes, thanks for your reply. I didn't try to remove it yet. Is it ok to remove the constraint? I just wanted to be sure that the user_id actually exists when adding a record to this table.

Comment: I would at least try to see how much slower it is with the FK in place. For extreme TP you often trust the apps to do the right thing in these matters.

Comment: Hi @eckes! Thanks for your reply. Is that the only option? I see foreign keys as a tool for data integrity protection (like storing things for customers that actually exist). I understand that it takes an extra step checking if the provided id actually exists in the referenced table, but does it take that long?

Comment: Not the only Option But a good start to try. If it is faster after dropping it you know what to optimize, if it is not faster you know what you don’t need to worry about (and recreate it)

Comment: @TJistooshort - Show us a sample `INSERT`.  We need to see whether it is a 1-row insert, a batch a `LOAD DATA`, `INSERT..SELECT..`, `INSERT IGNORE`, or something else

Comment: eckes, TJ -- The FK check is a small overhead; probably to info that is currently cached in the buffer_pool (in this case).  _Usually_ the application has just done something that assures that the 'foreign' guy is there, thereby making the integrity check totally redundant.  (I think this is what eckes means.)  TJ's point about adding an extra check is valid -- that would be more costly than using an FK.

Comment: @TJistooshort - Please provide `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM user_actions GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY 1 DESC` . This will give a clue of how intensive your non-intensive `SELECT` can get.

Comment: Hello @RickJames. [Here](https://pastebin.com/HUAQudkQ) is the output for that query. It returned 57926 records in 1.22 seconds.

Comment: Regarding the type of insert, is just a simple ```INSERT INTO``` statement that inserts one single row (basically when the user tries to access any endpoint, the application "captures" that request, log the relevant information (url, request data, user_id, current datetime) and that's inserted into the table

Comment: @TJistooshort Please post your COMPLETE - INSERT statement so we can see all the things the optimizer has to deal with.  And  it looks like you may run EXPLAIN INSERT ......  in your 5.7 version of MySQL.  Post complete text of EXPLAIN INSERT results  and SHOW WARNINGS; will have the content of HOW the optimizer rearranged your query for processing.  Thanks

Comment: @TJistooshort - Is the `INSERT` inside a transaction?  If so, what else is going on in it?  Ditto for the `SELECT`.

Comment: @WilsonHauck thanks for your reply. This is an example of one INSERT statement that took 5.3 seconds: ```insert into `user_actions` (`http_method`, `route_name`, `query_string`, `ip_address`, `user_agent`, `request_data`, `user_id`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values ('GET', '19-chars-string', '64-chars-string', '123.123.123.123', '139-chars-string', '[]', 96411, '2018-11-29 18:49:08', '2018-11-29 18:49:08');```

Comment: EXPLAIN INSERT returns: select_type: INSERT, table: user_actions, partitions: NULL, type: ALL, possible_keys: user_actions_user_id_foreign and the remaining fields are null (key, key_len, ref, rows, filtered, Extra)

Comment: Now that we can see your INSERT request, please post results of these requests to pastebin.com A) SHOW CREATE TABLE user_actions; B) SHOW INDEX FROM user_actions; C) EXPLAIN INSERT ...... and within the insert SESSION, D) SHOW WARNINGS; so we can see how the optimizer managed the INSERT.  Another helpful detail would be the posting of the results of findfragtables.sql to get an idea of the 'age' of your tables, row counts, DATA Space and FREE Space.  Posting last 400 lines of your Slow-log would also be informative.  Thanks

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @WilsonHauck. Here are the outputs for each requested command: [A](https://pastebin.com/EHLqv4e4), [B](https://pastebin.com/RqhcXKmw), [C](https://pastebin.com/thApPp2G) and for D, I tried multiple inserts and the output is always empty (zero rows).

Comment: @TJistooshort C & D must be run in ONE SESSION.   As soon as C ends, then SHOW WARNINGS in the next session will always be blank.    Please post results of findfragtables.sql when time permits.  On our website look under Utility Scripts+ and download for a $0.00 Order/Invoice total.  No payment method is required to dowload our free scripts.  With this information, we may know why we are looking at 5 seconds to insert a row.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it takes time (possibly more than 2 seconds) to shovel tens of thousands of rows. Disks, networks, etc, are not fast enough to go faster.

Meanwhile, such a `SELECT` is interfering, at some level, with anything else that is going on -- such as an `INSERT` that might be hitting the same user_id.

Also, are you using `autocommit = 1`, which commits each statement as you go.  Or are you using `=0` or `BEGIN`, in which case groups of statements are bunched together into a "transaction"?  This can impact on how one connection is interfering with another.

When you say that a 1-row `INSERT` is taking 2 seconds, what tool are you using for the timing?  To an end-user something can 'feel' like 2 seconds, but the real cause may be something else.

(Analysis of `VARIABLES` and `STATUS`:)

**Observations:**

- Version: 5.7.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log
- 16 GB of RAM
- Uptime = 4d 00:07:33
- You are not running on Windows.
- Running 64-bit version
- You appear to be running entirely (or mostly) InnoDB.

**The More Important Issues:**

Wow!  This is the first VARIABLES+STATUS I have review for which I saw nothing 'important' to fix.

**Details and other observations:**

`( Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_free / Innodb_buffer_pool_pages_total ) = 451,008 / 786432 = 57.3%` -- Pct of buffer_pool currently not in use
-- innodb_buffer_pool_size is bigger than necessary?

`( innodb_print_all_deadlocks ) = innodb_print_all_deadlocks = OFF` -- Whether to log all Deadlocks.
-- If you are plagued with Deadlocks, turn this on. Caution: If you have lots of deadlocks, this may write a lot to disk.

`( net_buffer_length / max_allowed_packet ) = 16,384 / 16M = 0.10%`

`( local_infile ) = local_infile = ON`
-- local_infile = ON is a potential security issue

`( Select_scan / Com_select ) = 226,117 / 2089280 = 10.8%` -- % of selects doing full table scan. (May be fooled by Stored Routines.)
-- Add indexes / optimize queries

`( back_log / max_connections ) = 80 / 151 = 53.0%`

**Abnormally large:**

```
innodb_page_cleaners = 12
performance_schema_max_file_classes = 80
performance_schema_max_mutex_classes = 210
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @RickJames. The current setting is ```autocommit = 1```. I used a client called Sequel Pro in order to see how long it took to run that query.

Comment: There's gotta be something else that we are not seeing.  2 seconds for a simple `INSERT` is "impossible".

Comment: I agree. I will inspect the code to see if I can find other issues (that could eventually lead to this situation)

Comment: @TJistooshort  Please post to pastebin.com TEXT results of A) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS: B) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; C) from your Linux Command prompt results of ulimit -a  please for discovery of how your instance is really configured and running.

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @WilsonHauck. Here is the output for each command: [Show Global Status](https://pastebin.com/zd4knGAg), [Show Global Variables](https://pastebin.com/eqA50RFf) and [ulimit -a](https://pastebin.com/uG7Sy6gi), Thanks in advance

Comment: @TJistooshort - I added analysis -- but nothing exciting in it.

Comment: @TJistooshort - How many tables in your system?  I see the low default of `ulimit` of 1024.  However, `table_open_cache` is 2000.  This is inconsistent??  (Meanwhile, `Table_open_cache_hits/misses` looks fine.)

Comment: Thanks very much for your reply @RickJames. Currently I have 58 tables. I'm not sure about the ulimit/table_open_cache settings. Should the match? I will research about it because I'm not familiar with those two settings

Comment: @TJistooshort - The hits/misses say "nothing needs changing".  The `ulimit` and `table_open_cache` are inconsistent, so I don't what the issue is.  Normally, the OS's `ulimit` (1024) is noticed (by mysqld), and `table_open_cache is set to about 1/3 of that.  Other than that, the `2000` is a reasonable setting.

Answer (score 0):

Rate Per Second=RPS  Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
read_rnd_buffer_size=192K  # from 256K to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS
innodb_io_capacity=1900  # from 200 to use more of your IOPS capacity
thread_cache_size=32  # from 8 to accomodate more connections when you grow
innodb_lru_scan_depth=100  # from 256 to reduce 60% of CPU cycles used every SECOND for this function.
```

Possible areas to research.
Deletes, Inserts, Updates of 91 Million actions in 4 days?

Not one ALTER, ANALYZE or OPTIMIZE table in 4 days?

42 deadlocks in 4 days.  If they could be eliminated, you should.

For additional suggestions, please view my profile, Network profile for contact info and get in touch via Skype, please.  We do have a findfragtables.sql utility that will identify tables that are fragmented.  A free utility.